# Reset subEntityId as empty once desired task is executed in MS Teams Tabs

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have enabled deep linking in Microsoft Teams Tabs. We are generating link to the custom tabs with subEntityId as mentioned in Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links)

`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>?webUrl=<entityWebUrl>&label=<entityLabel>&context=<context>`

In home page, we are using Ms Teams Js SDK and calling getContext() for retrieving the subEntityId passed in the URL.

We used the following code for navigating to different page based on subEntityId

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
    console.log(context);
    let currentUrl = window.location.href;
    let isAdmin = false;
    if(currentUrl.indexOf('admin') > 0){
        isAdmin = true;
    }
   let subEntityId = context.subEntityId;
    let redirectUrl = "";
    if(subEntityId == "all-tasks")
    {
        redirectUrl = isAdmin ? 
        window.location.origin + "/admin/task/all-tasks" :
        window.location.origin + "/member/task/all-tasks";
    }
     microsoftTeams.setContext
     if(redirectUrl != ""){
        window.location.assign(redirectUrl);
     }
});
```

but when we are navigating back to home page using navigation bar (not by using any back button) it is automatically redirecting back. The subEntityId is not resetting and on home page load it is picking the id and navigating again.

Please help, is there any possible way to reset or set the subEntityId as empty.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understood your point correctly, then you have added this script in home page so that you will redirect the user to respective page based on role (admin/member). And when you navigate back to home page, again it redirect to admin/member page. Is this correct ?

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Thanks for replying. Yes the script is in the home page and it is redirecting based on the role in website url and if subEntityId is present then i am redirecting  to specific page. When i am navigating back to home page, the script is picking up the subEntityId and again redirecting it. Admin/Member are two different view to isolate the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no way to change the context, or otherwise record that the subEntityId has already been followed once, using the Teams client SDK

My solution was to add a hash or url parameter to the tab's contentURL (during tab configuration).

```
microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
    contentUrl: https://my_tab_url#follow_deep_link,
})
```

Then the subEntityId is only used when this hash is present. Subsequent navigation within the tab removes the #follow_deep_link and subEntityId is not used.

```
if (window.location.hash === '#follow_deep_link') {
  microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
    //handle subEntityId
  })
}
```

Comment: Can confirm this works. Nice workaround! A bit hacky but it will do until we have an api for it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code to update subEntityId value after redircting.

```
microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
                    subEntityId: "Reset value here",                        
                });
```

Comment: settings are used for the tab configuration, whilst the subEntityId is part to the context object (which I think is read only). Attempting to set the settings appears to cause the tab to reload.