# subEntityId in teams tab app not persisting after refresh/navigation to another tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

We're creating a teams tab app with ties into the activity feed notifications for the user. When the user selects the activity feed entry, we open our app with a specific subEntityId to display only information pertaining to that notification (and doesn't allow free navigation of the app). It's all working great, until the user either refreshes or navigates to another tab in our app... At that point, the subEntityId is no longer passed into the app context.

See our manifest entry below:

```
    "staticTabs": [
        {
          "entityId": "web-radio",
          "name": "Web Radio",
          "contentUrl": "https://**redacted**/teams?id={subEntityId}",
          "scopes": [
              "personal"
          ]
        },
        {
          "entityId": "live-look",
          "name": "Live Look",
          "contentUrl": "https://**redacted**/teams/live?id={subEntityId}",
          "scopes": [
              "personal"
          ]
        }
    ],
```

We're calling the graph api to post to the activity feed. example looks like this:

```
{
  topic: {
    source: 'text',
    value: '**redacted**',
    webUrl: 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/1f86b80f-fcd2-44f9-8602-6266fd7db1ef/web-radio?context=%7B%22subEntityId%22%3A%2263e56462-5e93-4256-8c7a-eccff2ffa314%22%7D'
  },
  previewText: { content: 'Patrick Burrus: 1234' },
  activityType: 'message',
  recipients: [
    {
      '@odata.type': 'microsoft.graph.aadUserNotificationRecipient',
      userId: '**redacted**'
    }
  ],
  templateParameters: [ { name: 'message', value: 'New message in Patrick Burrus' } ]
}
```

Is there a way we can maintain the subEntityId while the user has our app open from the activity feed? We'd like to limit the app navigation when opened from the activity feed.

Comment: Got the related thread-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61664023/reset-subentityid-as-empty-once-desired-task-is-executed-in-ms-teams-tabs#:~:text=There%20appears%20to%20be%20no%20way%20to%20change,%28during%20tab%20configuration%29.%20microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings%20%28%7B%20contentUrl%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fmy_tab_url%23follow_deep_link%2C%20%7D%29
Are you trying the same?

Meanwhile we are checking it from our end and get back to you.

Comment: Could you please confirm once are you passing subEntityId through manifest or pass through activity feed notifications?

Comment: Added our manifest entry and an example post to /teamwork/sendActivityNotificationToRecipients above.

Comment: Thanks for providing information we will check this internally and get back to you.

Comment: @PatrickBurrus-weavix-
This behavior is currently by design. We wipe out the subEntityId on navigation.